# Mouse Binding Question with Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, window, mouse

Wondering how to bind an event to the left mouse button but not having to be hovered in the window/app/root. Basically, I want the event to happen where-ever my mouse pointer happens to be on my screen. Right now I can only figure out how to make the mouse button bindings work when the mouse is hovered on the window/app/root.

```
    from tkinter import*
    from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar
    import random
    import pyautogui

    root = Tk()
    root.configure(background='black')
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.geometry("100x100")

    title_bar = Frame(root, bg='black')
    title_bar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    tout = StringVar()
    label = Label(root, textvariable=tout, font=('TkDefaultFont', 
    50), bg='black', fg='red')
    label.pack()

    def _quit():
        root.quit()
        root.destroy()

    def move_app(event):
        root.geometry(f'+{event.x_root}+{event.y_root}')

    def gen_rand(event):
        randvar = random.randint(0,99)
        tout.set(randvar)

    def clear_rand(event):
        tout.set("")

    myButton = Button(title_bar, text="X", font=('TkDefaultFont', 5), 
    bg='black', activebackground='red', fg='red', command=_quit)
    myButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

    root.bind('<Button-1>', gen_rand)
    root.bind('<Button-3>', clear_rand)
    root.bind("<B2-Motion>", move_app)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with tkinter, you'll have to find some platform-specific way to do it. Tkinter can only process events when it is the application in focus.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be done with Tkinter,
but rather Pyautogui to generate an event

```
pyautogui.click(x=100, y=200)  # move to 100, 200, then click the left mouse button.
```

if you wish to read an event you must use other module such as pynput
[How to know if the left mouse click is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235454/how-to-know-if-the-left-mouse-click-is-pressed)

````py
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        print('{} at {}'.format('Pressed Left Click' if pressed else 'Released Left Click', (x, y)))
        return False # Returning False if you need to stop the program when Left clicked.
    else:
        print('{} at {}'.format('Pressed Right Click' if pressed else 'Released Right Click', (x, y)))

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
listener.join()```

  [1]: https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235454/how-to-know-if-the-left-mouse-click-is-pressed
````

Comment: Thank you for your response. I seem to still be stuck. I installed pyautogui and i imported it but not sure how the code should look. I just posted the code in the original question

Comment: Oh my mistake , pyautogui could only make an event if you want to listen to events you must use other module such as pynput. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Im so new to this im still lost. I just want my random number generator to change numbers by left clicking no matter where the cursor is.