# How to exit a loop when any key is pressed?

Tags: python

I would like Python to run the following code in a loop e.g.

```
while(True): 
   pyautogui.moveTo(844,222)
   pyautogui.click(interval=2)
```

until ANY button is pressed so that the logic can continue as follows:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("1"):
    pyautogui.moveTo(1021,308)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(958,771)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(961,531)
    
if keyboard.is_pressed("2"):
    pyautogui.moveTo(1446,308)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(958,771)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(961,531)
```

Comment: This can be done using the `pynput` library. Reference: [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/), Also, there is no way to do this in `pyautogui`

Comment: Could you please give an example of how this would work  ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have experience with this library, you can see this question for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235454/how-to-know-if-the-left-mouse-click-is-pressed

Answer (score -1):

This should work :)

```
!pip install keyboard
import keyboard

while True:
    # do your stuff
    if keyboard.read_key() != "":
        break

#continu here
```