# Python wait for click

Tags: python, onclick, pyautogui

I'm making a script in Python (without an interface) that requires the user to click certain places on the screen so I can retrieve the mouse position.

With `pyautogui` it's pretty easy to get the `position` of the mouse. Yet, there seems to be no click event, wait click or anything like that.

Considering that the click can be **ANYWHERE** (including outside of the IDE, and even if the IDE is minimized), is there any way to get a click event or actively wait for a click?

Comment: Can you use [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)? [E.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62661562/2280890)

Comment: @importrandom, sounds like a good thing to try

Comment: Does the job for me.

Comment: You could also use [mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/), although it isn't great. Only thing you could do is check if a mouse click happened, using `mouse.is_pressed('left')`, and you'd need a while loop to do that, just a suggestion in case `pynput`doesn't work.

Comment: pynput works well but not everywhere.... sometimes it captures the clicks outside the IDE, sometimes it doesn't, especially if the click is on another program.

Comment: mouse has the same problem as pynput.... although both do the job, none of them work when the click is on certain softwares

Comment: `Win32api` works for me in any window, try that.

Comment: See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165495/detecting-mouse-clicks-in-windows-using-python) (win32api answer).

Comment: Cool, @5rod, `win32api` works perfecly